# is there a name for adding an a. in a.table in an sql query?

Tags: mysql, sql

Person is a table with columns PersonId, FirstName, LastName

Address is a table with columns PersonId, City, State

```
SELECT a.FirstName, a.LastName, b.City, b.State
FROM Person a, Address b
WHERE a.PersonId = b.PersonId;
```

I have two questions.

1. Please correct me if I'm wrong, but I'm guessing that the purpose of the (a., b.) extensions are used to indicate a specific column of an SQL table so there exists no ambiguity between selecting a column given two tables may have the same column name?
2. Is there a name for this?

Comment: 1) yes 2) alias

Comment: Those are referred to as [Table Name Aliases](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/problems-with-alias.html), where column names can also be aliased. eg. `SELECT a.FirstName AS f_name`

Answer (score 2):

These are called table aliases, and indeed their purpose is to indicate from which table each column comes from. This is mandatory to avoid ambiguity when a column by the same name exists in both tables - but also a general good practice, so people reading the query can understand it without having knowledge of the underlying table structures.

Note that you don’t necessarily need *explicit* aliases; you can also prefix the columns with the full table name if you like (like `Person.FirstName`): aliases just makes things shorter to write.

You should use meaningful aliases so it is easier to remember them through the query (`Person` would be best aliases `p` than `a`).

Finally, you should be using explicit, modern joins (with the `on` keyword) rather than old-school, implicit joins, whose syntax is not state of the art since ANSI SQL 92, decades ago.

Your query:

```
SELECT p.FirstName, p.LastName, a.City, a.State
FROM Person p
INNER JOIN Address a ON a.PersonId = p.PersonId;
```

Answer (score 2):

> *2. Is there a name for this?*

It's called giving identifier. In `SELECT city.Name FROM city;` `city` is the identifier to `Name`, in `SELECT c.Name FROM city c;` however alias `c` is the identifier to `Name`.

> *1. Please correct me if I'm wrong, but I'm guessing that the purpose
>   of
>       the (a., b.) extensions are used to indicate a specific column of an
>       SQL table so there exists no ambiguity between selecting a column
>       given two tables may have the same column name?*

This is true apart from the aliases. One can achieve this without aliases by referencing the exact names of the tables.

Aliases help,

- Changing the related table name in one place and in one place alone

  e.g.

  changing `sales` to `stock` in

```
    SELECT *
    FROM sales s
    WHERE s.col1 ... s.col2 ... s.col3 ...
    -- WHERE sales.col1 ... sales.col2 ... sales.col3 ...
```

is relatively easier.

- Simplify the details of the query by shortening the columns refered

  e.g.

  It's harder to understand the query below than the one where it has
  simple aliases:

  ```
  SELECT 
    product_color_configuration.Name
  FROM product_color_configuration
  LEFT JOIN product_channel_permission ON product_color_configuration.ProductId = product_channel_permission.ProductId ...
  ```
- Remove the ambiguity when the same table is referenced multiple
  times distinctly:

  ```
  SELECT
    COALESCE(c1.Name, c2.Name) -- if Id exists prioritize
  FROM table t
  LEFT JOIN city c1 ON t.CityId = c1.Id
  LEFT JOIN city c2 ON c2.Name REGEXP t.CityGuessedName
  ;
  ```

Answer (score 2):

Generally it's called an **identifier qualifier:**

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/identifier-qualifiers.html

> ...a column name may be given a table-name qualifier, which itself may
>   be given a database-name qualifier. Examples of unqualified and
>   qualified column references in SELECT statements:
>
> ```
> SELECT c1 FROM mytable
> WHERE c2 > 100;
>
> SELECT mytable.c1 FROM mytable
> WHERE mytable.c2 > 100;
>
> SELECT mydb.mytable.c1 FROM mydb.mytable
> WHERE mydb.mytable.c2 > 100;
> ```

You can use a table alias as a qualifier either to make it shorter than the full table name, or because you are doing a self-join and you use aliases to make more than one reference to the same table name.

> ```
> SELECT c1, c2, t1.c FROM db1.t AS t1 INNER JOIN db2.t AS t2
> WHERE t2.c > 100;
> ```